# Folder References from JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Supposed you had the following setup in your WAP project.

In your root you had:

```
SomeFile.js
Images [folder]
```

and you had some javascript referencing an image:

iContainer.src = "images/" + s;

You then moved the .js file to Content\JS folder:

```
Content[folder]
    js[folder]
       SomeFile.js
```

and you moved images folder to Content\Images

```
Content[folder]
    images[folder]
```

The content folder is also in the root of the web project.

Then would you change that javascript to this:

```
sContainer.src = "/content/images/" + s;
```

or this:

```
sContainer.src = "../../content/images/" + s;
```

I think /content and content/ is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **../images/** would do the work

Comment: is that basically the only syntax that would work?  obviously you can't do a ~/ in javascript.